# foursquare API get filtered list of restaurants

Tags: foursquare

I was checking docs https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/

And can see information how to get some data about the venues, but there no description how to get the list of venues. For example I need to get list of all restaurant in Los Angeles, how can I do it? if it's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `v2/venues/search` endpoint.
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

e.g.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?
categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259 // food category
&near=Los+Angeles
&limit=50 // up to 50
&oauth_token=(YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN)
&v=20170901
```

It's difficult to get list of **ALL** restaurant in Los Angeles because `limit` parameter is up to 50.

Use `v2/venues/categories` endpoint to get `categoryId` list.
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories

```
- Food (4d4b7105d754a06374d81259)
  - Afghan Restaurant (503288ae91d4c4b30a586d67)
  - American Restaurant (4bf58dd8d48988d14e941735)
  - Chinese Breakfast Place (52af3a903cf9994f4e043bee)
  ...
```